# Excel: Count of unique items while ignoring junk duplicates

Tags: excel, count, duplicates

I have a column with IDs and I need a count of the unique IDs only. The problem is that not all rows have unique IDs so those rows have a junk code of 99999. Also there can be text in the ID sometimes and it looks like this: D-00000

Right now to get a rough total I count the whole list and subtract the count of 99999s out, but the original count has regular duplicates in it that are not the 99999 code so my count is too high.

I can't just subtract the duplicate count from the total because the 99999s will get counted with standard duplicates.

Here are the first 25 values for an example:

> 50658
>   48762
>   8536
>   99999
>   D-33667
>   99999
>   50659
>   50660
>   3684
>   898
>   34157
>   99999
>   D-52412
>   52439
>   99999
>   99999
>   99999
>   45216
>   31718
>   31718
>   50664
>   50665
>   99999
>   99999
>   34171

Out of those 25, there are 8 99999s. Out of the remaining 17, there is one duplicate (31718 is in there twice) meaning the unique count would be 16.

I am pretty sure I could do it by making an extra column and using IF statements to ignore the 99999s but copy anything else, then do a unique item count on that column, but I would really love to know if this is possible with just single formula because it would be a powerful tool to have (a single formula which can then be used on any sheet anywhere any time it is needed) and would not be as dangerous as a hidden column in my sheet. Also deconstructing a sheet to add a column in the middle then reconstructing it while making sure not to break everything else is a huge headache, especially since this list is over 10k rows...

Thank you very much to anyone who feels like spending some time on this puzzle. :)

Comment: I just had an idea...what if I used a regular duplicates count with an IF statement that would subtract an extra 1 if it detected a 99999 duplicate...that might be way easier than my original idea...

Buuuuuut I can't tell I have been writing formulas all week and my brain is officially just returning me #NO when trying to imagine this at this point. -_- 

Anyway, does anyone think that will work instead maybe?

Comment: I tested Wisely's solution, it works pretty well but I am not understanding the logic of the formula.  Give it a try.

Comment: @Corinne Your idea is what I did in my solution -- counted all the duplicates and subtracted one if `99999` was present.  Mine is a single cell solution.  But you could use an extra hidden column with formulas; and you don't need to put the column in the middle -- it could just as easily be at the end.

Comment: Ming, yes I tried and and paired it with what Ron said and now it works. :)

=IF(COUNTIF($G17:G2000,99999)>0,SUMPRODUCT(($G17:G2000<>"")/COUNTIF($G17:G2000,$G17:G2000&""))-1,SUMPRODUCT(($G17:G2000<>"")/COUNTIF($G17:G2000,$G17:G2000&"")))

I agree though that I wish I understood how the duplicate formula works, but at least it works well inside of the IF statement so I am happy. ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say your column is column A with IDs from row A2-A26, on A28 try this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A26<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A26,A2:A26&""))`

It worked for my other project.  It doesn't need to create another column or table.

Comment: This is wicked smart.  Use this!!  But can you explain this formula a little more?

Comment: I can't figure out how to paste code in the box...

Anyway this is what I managed to work out using your very useful formula:

=IF(COUNTIF($G17:G2000,99999)>0,SUMPRODUCT(($G17:G2000<>"")/COUNTIF($G17:G2000,$G17:G2000&""))-1,SUMPRODUCT(($G17:G2000<>"")/COUNTIF($G17:G2000,$G17:G2000&"")))

I have no idea how it works though! :P I tried to follow it in Evaluation but it fills up with way too much text to scroll through in that little window. Obviously I can tell that it is a very compact duplicate checker which I am very grateful for...just wish I could tell how/why it works haha. Thank you!

Comment: @Corinne, let say you want to count the unique items from B3 to B40.  Just copy the code `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A26<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A26,A2:A26&""))` and go to an empty cell, press F2, paste the code and change all A2:A26 to B3:B40.

Comment: Yes I have used the code as is with adjusted references. :) My version just also includes an IF statement to check if any 99999s are detected at all, since it will count it at least once if it is there. If (count of 99999 > 0) then (unique count formula - 1) else (unique count formula). :3

So yeah, I don't know how the unique count formula works on a step by step basis (viewing it through evaluation isn't possible with how big it gets) but it is WAY more compact than all other unique count formulas/solutions I have seen in the past (many require multiple columns) so I'm very happy with it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pivot table the data and put IDs under the ROWS field.  Then you can use `counta()` to count how many unique IDs you will have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no blanks in your list, try the following **array** formula.  Enter the formula with **`ctrl+shift+enter`**.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces **`{...}`** around the formula

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(IDs,IDs))-(COUNTIF(IDs,99999)>0)
```

IDs is the range containing your ID numbers.  EG  A2:A26